# Updating Outdated Package

Tags: apt, updates

I have installed the `jdupes` using `sudo apt install jdupes` but the version I am running is very old and latest version `jdupes-1.27.3` is not available for my OS.

Could you guide me how to update to latest version?

Thank you

```
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal

jdupes -v
jdupes 1.14.0 (2019-12-30) 64-bit
```

Comment: 1.14 is the only version available for 20.04. AskUbuntu will not help you install unofficial versions. But good news Ubuntu 24.04 has 1.27.3-5 if you're willing to risk `do-release-upgrade -d`. Or if you're willing to settle for 1.26.1-1, you can `do-release-upgrade` to 23.10.

Comment: Thank you Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of jdupes. Go to https://codeberg.org/jbruchon/jdupes/releases and download the Linux x86_64 tar.xz file. Extract the jdupes binary. Put it in your home directory and use it by typing ~/jdupes instead. Or, you can overwrite the system binary at /usr/bin/jdupes if you feel a bit frisky.

Comment: Ok, if you're the author, then I suppose this is somewhat supported then. If a user wants to put a binary on the PATH on Ubuntu, then it's usually ~/.local/bin. Administrators install locally to /usr/local/bin/jdupes. However, avoid overwriting anything like /usr/bin/jdupes. Apt may cause it to suddenly stop working someday. If you really must, you should use dpkg-divert before doing that

Comment: You're right. A package update will overwrite the system binary. Better to stuff it in /usr/local/bin